# Can't Login to EC2 instance after changing Public to Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache2

I have a EC2 linux server, where a website was running properly on Apache web server. It was running on a public IP.

I changed the public IP to Elastic IP but it stopped my website.

So I again detached Elastic IP, and a new Public IP was assigned to me.

But now my website is not working. The Security group is okay. I can ping and ssh the server with new Public IP, but website not running.

Strangely, when I paste new Public IP in browser, it redirects to my old public after trying for 10 seconds. Any help is appreciated.

This is my Virtual Host configuration:

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin abc@coaching.com
    DocumentRoot /all_data/wordpress
    ServerName abccoaching.com
    ErrorLog logs/coaching_error.log
    CustomLog logs/coaching_custom.com.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Where do I put my Elastic ( Or Public ) IP? Strangely, there is no error reported in Apache error logs.

Comment: Best guess is apache is configured incorrectly. For a public web server you should be using an Elastic IP, not the default public IP, because as you've found, it can change if you stop and start the server. If you want more concrete help you'll need to edit your question to include error logs, diagnostic information, and apache configuration.

Comment: Tim, I have added my apache config. There is no error logs. Where do I define Elastic IP in Apache?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Apache, I use Nginx. Suggest you find the logs. Looks like you listen on whatever IP is available on port 80, which looks fine to me, not knowing apache.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am correct but as you said that when you are browsing with new public IP then it redirecting to you to old public IP, Your Old public IP could be hard coded in your code or database. You can try to check the website configuration and inspect the element.

Comment: No, its not hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a server problem to me but like a WordPress problem/feature. I used to do backups to S3 of my WP-Server. I just copied all files and a database dump every couple of hours to S3 to use it for disaster recovery. 
I practised that once. I set up a new EC2 instance (with the AMI I used for the old one) with obviously new IP address and copied all files from S3 to the new EC2 instance. I was surprised to see most of the clicks on the website being redirected to the old server/old IP-address. After doing some research, I found out that it had to do with the WP-configuration and that I had to treat the moving to the "new" server like migrating to a completely new environment. I was surprised to see that in the WP-configuration were references to the IP-address and not only to the domain name, which was moved too. 
I checked this https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and a couple of other links, followed the listed steps and it worked.

Comment: Hi, this does not look like wordpress issue. I temporary changed my document root in Apache to another location, which only have 1 file ( index.html ) and restarted Apache. Still same result.